# Unable to get the value of the Variable

Tags: python, geturl

Hi I have two lines of code which is

```
url1 = print(driver.current_url)
```

web url :  "https://www.journal-officiel.gouv.fr/balo/recherche/resultats?parutionDateStart=2021-05-05&parutionDateEnd=2021-05-05&_token=9OFJ6Ry1SbhZ8bkxPSNx1Z8xtlSeyMV1-xpo3S7D-ms"

I am doing this as the link is dynamic and varies with every date.

In this in the jupiter ide it shows the current url which is there and get printed in the bottom , but when i call the variable url1 or print url1 it not giving any value.How can i get the url while calling url1 here

Answer (score 1):

```
print(driver.current_url)
```

Here `print` function does two things,

- First, It prints `driver.current_url` to the console.
- Second it will return `None`(If a function does not return anything
  python will implicitly return `None`).

So the value of `url1` after `url1 = print(driver.current_url)` statement will be  will be `None`.

Looks like what you need is ,

```
url1 = driver.current_url
print(url1)
```